# Laravel API Route Put/Patch Method : Error - The GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Version : 7
File Path : 'routes/api.php'

I have an api route only for PUT/PATCH, i dont have GET route for this endpoint.

in routes/api.php :

```
Route::match( ['put', 'patch'], 'phc/client/edit', 'Api\\PhcUserController@putByNo')->middleware('checkTypeUser:ecommerce' );
```

When i try this route with Postman, using PUT Method i get this error :

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT, PATCH.
```

What i have done wrong ?

note: i have other GET endpoints and all work well, i started working in the PUT/PATCH method and now this error appear. I cannot use Route::Resource because i dont have control off the models in database.

Here is the postman screenshot
[Postman Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9WQq.png)

Even with _method: PUT
[Postman Form Data : "_method" : "PUT"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNsdZ.png)

LARAVEL route:list

[terminal : php artisan route:list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Fui.png)

**NEW INFORMATION**
*I was working on a remote server by ssh. I imported the project to my local machine server, and all works fine.
So i think it's some kind of remote server configuration issue, the server uses NGINX/APACHE. Because the remote serve is not managed by me, i reported the issue to the company who does.
I will get new information soon, i Hope it helps another with the same problem.*

**NEW INFORMATION - PART II**
*The server reported that all is working fine :(. Why my laravel works well on PUT/PATCH on local server, but on remote server it does not work ?*

Comment: Could you please share your postman request, eg by exporting it to curl? Thanks.

Comment: here message is clear `['put', 'patch']` you are allowing put and patch but try to access `Get` or add get in here`['get','put', 'patch']` to solve this

Comment: but i dont want to create a get method for this endpoint, why i shoul put a GET method ? In postman i'm not trying to use GET, i use PUT ou PATCH

Comment: @Pirex360 use "any" instead of put or patch or get

Comment: @sandy, but if i use "any" , ok it works... 
But when i try to access GET method of this endpoint the user not receive a message method not exists... because any, gives the endpoint a GET method....i dont want to give the endpoint the GET method. It is possible this way ?

Comment: Does your `public function putByNo()` use any `->validate()` logic? If so, you need to be aware that if that function fails, it performs a redirect to the same URL, as a `GET` request.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis, i dont use any validate() logic. In fact, i comment all  code in the public function putByNo(). And the error is the same :(

Comment: Hmm, the only other guess would be something in the middleware performing a redirect? What does your `->middleware('checkTypeUser:ecommerce');` contain? I'm pretty certain that somewhere along your request, it is being interrupted and redirected, otherwise, this should work... If you added a basic `Route::get('/test', function(){ return response()->json(['message' => 'success']) });`, then tried to POSTMan to that, it should work, otherwise something else is very wrong with your setup :)

Comment: @KamleshPaul, Thanks for your help. I cannot use ['get' ... ] in my endpoints because it will be a pain, and i dont use it. Also i use scribe for API auto documentation... the GET endpoints will create documentation, without need.

Comment: @TimLewis, inside middleware :
`
$userdata = Auth::user();
        // if type was any word from db usertype
        // permits multiple roles
        if (strstr($type, $userdata->usertype)) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            // no valid
            return redirect('/');
        }
`

Comment: So there is a redirect there, is it hitting that? And do you have a `GET` request handler for `Route::get('/', ...);`?

Comment: Yes, @TimLewis .. i just test without this middleware.... and the error is the same. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Damn... I'm stumped, sorry :(

Comment: @TimLewis, and the `Route::get('/test...`you mention works fine. So it's not my setup fault... the order of the Routes are important ?

Comment: Yes, the order of routes can make a difference, especially if you're using params, like `Route::get('/example/{param}', ...);` If you had `Route::get('/example/specific', ...);`, those  could potentially clash. I forget which takes precedence though, first defined or last defined.

Comment: I think i some error on POSTMAN, because i dont have the POST Method, i changed in POSTMAN do POST, and it ignores it and calls the function on the controller for PUT/PATCH the `public function putByNo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the remote server, some NGINX bad configuration only permit GET/POST methods.

After they fix it, it works like in local.

Thanks for all the help.